# Can you use "expo build:ios" on a CI environment with apple 2 factor authentication and how

Tags: docker, expo, google-cloud-build

Is there a way to use `expo build:ios` on a CI environment and pass 2 factor authentication ?

I'm having troubles to start a build using expo on our CI environment due to the 2 factor authentication required for my apple developer account.

Is the `expo build:ios` command supposed to only be used locally or without 2 factor authentication ?

Running the build **locally** in interactive mode works - password and 2 factor auth was required only the first time I chose to build the app. For consecutive build I only use `expo build:ios --release-channel test` and that's it

My CI environment is google's Cloud Build - it runs in a Docker container, so I can't go and do a one time manual login to have the runner persist some session information like it happens locally can I?

---

After reading the cli usage information for `expo build:ios` and that you can setup your account password as ENV variable like `EXPO_APPLE_PASSWORD` I though it should be possible to use it in a CI environment

But then I get the following result:

```sh
expo login --non-interactive -u XXX

Success. You are now logged in as XXX.
```

```sh
expo build:ios --non-interactive --no-wait --release-channel test --apple-id XXXXX --team-id F7NE7X9ZFW
```

```sh
- Making sure project is set up correctly...
[16:43:00] Checking if there is a build in progress...
[16:43:00] Trying to authenticate with Apple Developer Portal...
Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account 'XXXXX'
More information about Two-factor Authentication: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915
If you're running this in a non-interactive session (e.g. server or CI)
check out https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification
...
Please enter the 6 digit code:
[16:43:02] Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
[16:43:02] Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "The input stream is exhausted."
```

So I follow the link for non-interactive sessions: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification

And I see that I have to create and use a `FASTLANE_SESSION` environment variable. 
But at that point I'm, not sure whether it will work as it seems this is coming from some tooling that expo uses internally.

I guess I can install `fastlane` locally and try to generate this variable with the command `fastlane spaceauth -u user@example.org`. I didn't find anything about this in the expo documentation though

There's information on using `expo build:ios` to build standalone apps, it covers only how to build them locally https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps/

They have a guide for a CI flow ("on Your CI") - but it's using `turtle-cli` and for iOS it requres to run on a mac environment - it covers how to do builds yourself on your own machine and not using `expo.io` https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/distribution/turtle-cli/

---

Another thing that I've tried is running like:

```sh
expo build:ios \
  --team-id YOUR_TEAM_ID \
  --dist-p12-path /path/to/your/dist/cert.p12 \
  --provisioning-profile-path /path/to/your/provisioning/profile.mobileprovision
```

With the `EXPO_IOS_DIST_P12_PASSWORD` set as env variable but the build would fail as it still needs apple id and password

---

Is there a way that I can share or copy my local session - the session that expo created the first time I ran `build:ios` where I'm authenticated and I'm not prompted for password anymore to the CI machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me in the end:

I've created another bundle identifier `com.myawesome.stuff`
I've also generated/created:

- Distribution Certificate P12  `--dist-p12-path`
- Push Key .p8 file - `--push-id` and `--push-p8-path`
- Provisioning Profile. - `--push-p8-path`

Then **locally** I've run the following:

Login interactively

```sh
expo login
```

Authenticate with apple interactively

```sh
expo build:ios --clear-credentials --apple-id my@appleId.com --team-id=TheTeam --dist-p12-path=dist.p12 --provisioning-profile-path=profile.mobileprovision --push-p8-path=push.p8 --push-id=THEID --release-channel test
```

*Tobe fair I've run those locally but in the google cloud console terminal*

Then **on the CI environment** we just use:

```sh
expo login --non-interactive "--username=XXXX"
```

```sh
expo build:ios --non-interactive --no-wait "--release-channel=$BRANCH_NAME"
```

Which works and produces the following log

```
- Making sure project is set up correctly...
[17:48:39] Checking if there is a build in progress...

[17:48:40] Fetching available credentials
[17:48:40] Unable to validate distribution certificate due to insufficient Apple Credentials
[17:48:40] Unable to validate Push Keys due to insufficient Apple Credentials
- Performing best effort validation of Provisioning Profile...

[xmldom error]  element parse error: Error: invalid tagName: 
@#[line:99,col:125]
[xmldom error]  element parse error: Error: invalid tagName: 
@#[line:114,col:75]
[xmldom error]  element parse error: Error: invalid tagName: 
@#[line:143,col:84]
✔ Successfully performed best effort validation of Provisioning Profile.
[17:48:40]
[17:48:40] Project Credential Configuration:
[17:48:40]   Experience: @XXXX/XXXX, bundle identifier: com.XXXXXXXX
[17:48:40]     Provisioning profile is missing. It will be generated during the next build
[17:48:40]     Apple Team ID: XXXXXXX,  Apple Team Name: ---------
[17:48:40]
[17:48:40]   Distribution Certificate - Certificate ID: -----
[17:48:40]     Apple Team ID: XXXXXXX,  Apple Team Name: ---------
[17:48:40]     used by
      @XXXX/XXXX (com.XXXXXXX)
[17:48:40]   Push Notifications Key - Key ID: XXXXXXXX
[17:48:40]     Apple Team ID: XXXXXXX,  Apple Team Name: ---------
[17:48:40]     used by
      @XXXX/XXXX (com.XXXXXXX)
[17:48:40] Unable to find an existing Expo CLI instance for this directory, starting a new one...
[17:48:42] Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
[17:48:46] Tunnel ready.
[17:48:46] Publishing to channel 'test'...
[17:48:47] Building iOS bundle
[17:50:13] Finished building JavaScript bundle in 60785ms.
[17:50:13] Building Android bundle
[17:51:04] Finished building JavaScript bundle in 51597ms.
[17:51:04] Analyzing assets
[17:51:06] Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1669ms.
[17:51:08] Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1526ms.
[17:51:08] Uploading assets
[17:51:08] No assets changed, skipped.
[17:51:08] Processing asset bundle patterns:
[17:51:08] - /workspace/**/*
[17:51:08] Uploading JavaScript bundles
[17:51:12] Published
[17:51:12] Your URL is

https://exp.host/@XXXX/XXXX?release-channel=test

[17:51:12] › Closing Expo server
[17:51:12] › Stopping Metro bundler
[17:51:13] Checking if this build already exists...

[17:51:13] Build started, it may take a few minutes to complete.
[17:51:13] You can check the queue length at https://expo.io/turtle-status

[17:51:13] You can make this faster. 
Get priority builds at: https://expo.io/settings/billing

[17:51:13] You can monitor the build at

 https://expo.io/dashboard/XXXX/builds/e5c32814-8613-4fef-889a-05ca982e952f

[17:51:13] Alternatively, run `expo build:status` to monitor it from the command line.
```

[image: check] Despite the troublesome warnings at the start the build works and produces an `.ipa` that we've successfully submitted to test flight

> [xmldom error]    element parse error: Error: invalid tagName: @#[line:99,col:125]
>
> [17:48:40]     Provisioning profile is missing. It will be generated during the next build

---

I think the problem might be that the google cloud build machine we're using is setup with a US location, but the last time I used the `expo build:ios` command locally on my pc I was in a different region. So just running `expo build:ios -clear-credentials` might be enough and you can let expo create and manage all the required certificates.

But nowhere did I found any information that on a `CI` (non interactive) environment you should use `expo build:ios` without providing apple id and credentials

Comment: It turns out `If you have credentials configured for your app on your expo account there is no need to authenticate with Apple on CI` so all I have to do is have the build done on my local computer once to have expo generate the credentials for me and associate them with my expo account, log in the same expo account on CICD and run the `expo:build:ios` command with NONE of the credential related arguments, voila!